# Element className inside MoodalBox?

Tags: javascript, mootools

On my site I've got a link that opens up a MoodalBox (http://www.e-magine.ro/web-dev-and-design/36/moodalbox/). The page displays fine, but I have an anchor on the page that calls a javascript function to change the className of a div (from hidden to visible).

I've debugged it all the way down to the actual function call that sets the className and found that the element was found properly and even that the className was successfully changed (no errors), but the element itself never changes. It works fine without a moodalbox.

Could someone shed some light? Thanks!

Comment: Have you watched what happens with Firebug?  That is, after the class name is updated, what does Firebug say about how the element is styled?

Comment: this is a VERY old script, 4 years and mootools 1 (which is archaic). it does not run very well, it's not written very well by today's standards, it offers no event support (onOpen, onComplete etc) and generally speaking, you're better off finding something else to use instead, like this http://iaian7.com/webcode/mediaboxAdvanced#inline (mootools 1.2+ and supports any number of options to modal). aside from that, using element.addClass("name") or .removeClass("name") is how it works in 1.11 (not sure on 1.0).

Comment: I've been trying to get MediaboxAdvanced working all afternoon. I have confirmed that no conflicting scripts are loaded, I've confirmed the relative paths of the images, I've confirmed that mootools 1.2.4 is being loaded, and that mediaboxAdv is being loaded, as well as its accompanying css. I click my link and it takes me to the page without the lightbox. What high-level reasons could this be relative to?

Comment: post a url - but basically, it's very easy, took me 3 mins to get video in a modal box: http://www.jsfiddle.net/Jau7L/ - make sure the files are being loaded, the doctype is fine and your markup on the links is correct

Comment: http://www.investordirector.com/directory/listing/guide/lenders_money_sources/loan_modification

If you click on the name, picture, or More Info, it is supposed to bring up what you see in the MediaboxAdvanced. I have confirmed with Firebug that the correct scripts are being loaded for that page; correct mootools version, correct MBA version, and the stylesheet.

Comment: "document.body is null" is an error I'm getting when the page that is hosting these boxes loads. This is in line 25 of the mediaboxadvanced script under "initialization". The js is failing before it even gets a chance to run:

window.addEvent("domready", function() {
// Create and append the Mediabox HTML code at the bottom of the document
$(document.body).adopt(

Comment: @Dimitar: thanks so much for your help. The bottom line is "get the heck off of Moodalbox!!". I've since opened a new question surrounding Mediabox and my specific area http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363605/document-body-is-null. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Hi Honus, please post an answer to this or ask Dimitar to do it so the question can be answered. Cheer