# document.body is null

Tags: javascript, mootools, mootools1.2

I've got a page where I'm using Mootools 1.2.4 and [MediaboxAdvanced](http://iaian7.com/webcode/mediaboxAdvanced) as a lightbox. I can't seem to get the thing working because of a particular javascript error

> document.body is null

at the initialization of Mediabox:

```
$(document.body).adopt(
     $$([
          overlay = new Element("div", {id: "mbOverlay"}).addEvent("click", close),
          center = new Element("div", {id: "mbCenter"})
     ]).setStyle("display", "none")
);
```

The page is [here](http://www.investordirector.com/directory/listing/guide/lenders_money_sources/mortgage_brokers). If yo uclick on the guy's name, picture, or the More Info button on the bottom right, it is supposed to launch the Mediabox. Via Firebug, I have confirmed that the CSS is loading, mootools is loading, and the Mediabox script is loading; all the paths to images and everything are correct as well.

Any ideas?

Comment: sorry about my dead-wrong answer :-) I've deleted it.

Comment: I don't get that error.  I get two others, though:  `unterminated parenthetical in mootools.js (line 67)` and `Accordion is not defined in mootools-accordion.js (line 7)`.

Comment: same - you need to load mootools-more (get it from http://mootools.net/more ), enable FX.accordion and it will auto-enable the dependencies you require.

Comment: Nice! Thanks! Cleared up that error just like you said!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may only be able to use $ on an element returned from getElementById.  A simple workaround is to instead use $$.

```
$$('body')[0].adopt...
```

Comment: also keep in mind the reason why it does not work is in your common.js: `function $(id) { return document.getElementById(id);}` - when mootools finds the $ is already defined, it drops into compatibility mode and refers to document.id as the alias for $. you can wrap calls to $ through mootools in an anon function like so: `(function($) { ... do stuff using $ })(document.id);` or you can remove the function from common.js as the mootools one will replicate the effect.

Comment: Understood. I'm not going to mess with it as it seems to be quite stable at this time. Your help was truly invaluable.