# "document.body is null" is fixed now I get ".setStyle is not a function"

Tags: javascript, lightbox, document-body

I'm running into a similar problem as this:

[link text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2363605/document-body-is-null)

I've done the fix as in the answer but now I end up with an error a couple lines later:

```
$$([overlay = (new Element("div", {id: "mbOverlay"})).addEvent("click", close), center = new Element("div", {id: "mbCenter"})]).setStyle is not a function [Break on this error] ]).setStyle("display", "none")
```

It's on this page:

[link text](http://hardedgecreative.com/superwicked.html)

When you click on 'showreel' it should pop up into the media box, but instead it just goes to a new page.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Troubleshoot. If it looks too complicated, it is. There are numerous debuggers available. setStyle is likely *undefined* - as to why, that's for you to find.

Answer (score 0):

At some point `$$([])` returns a NodeList, not a single element, and a NodeList has no setStyle method

```
$$([
    overlay = new Element("div", {id: "mbOverlay"})
        .addEvent("click", close),
    center = new Element("div", {id: "mbCenter"})
]).setStyle("display", "none");
```

I'm not certain why that is though... I'm not familiar with MooTools.